# How can open some other app from my app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have seen in my iPhone that through some apps, i am able to open Facebook and other apps installed in my iPhone.Can someone suggest me how to do this in my app.
Earlier iPhone doesn't allow us to do us,but i have heard that now it is possible in iPhone .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149129/can-i-launch-one-app-from-other-app-on-iphone

&

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629

Comment: @mokujin in my iPhone i am able to open Facebook app from my sync me app.

Comment: these link helped you...??

Comment: @mokujin No…i want to open the installed app from my app..n i have seen many apps doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via custom URL scheme. It is well documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

Comment: but i have seen SYNCME app opening Facebook app in iPhone

Comment: I didn't say you can't, you can do that using URL schemes :)
Facebook app implements some URL schemes using which you can open it via URL

Comment: but i want to open installed apps not through browser.

Comment: It will open installed app, not the browser... Please read the documentation in the link i posted. It explains everything, even has pretty pictures :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this using custom URL Schemes. See [Communicating with Other Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).

App B will need to register a custom URL Scheme which App A uses to launch B and pass it commands.

The following code fragment illustrates how one app can request the services of another app. “todolist” in this example is a hypothetical custom scheme registered by App B.

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```